# Greasemonkey @grant does not work anymore?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I have the following Greasemonkey script, which tries to read a resource text:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   test
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// @resource    testresource http://stackoverflow.com/
// ==/UserScript==

var text = GM_getResourceText('testresource');
```

I tried something like that a couple of weeks ago and it worked.
Now when I run this, GM_getResourceText can not be found:

> /*
>   Exception: ReferenceError: GM_getResourceText is not defined
>   @Scratchpad/7:9:5
>   */

I have Greasemonkey 3.1 on Firefox 37.0.2.
Does anyone else have the same problem and/or know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code should not give that error and `GM_getResourceText()` still works perfectly fine for me on Firefox 37.0.2 an Greasemonkey 3.1.

Make sure you are editing, and saving, the right copy of the script.  See [*How do I edit a script I'm working on?*](http://wiki.greasespot.net/FAQ#How_do_I_edit_a_script_I.27m_working_on.3F)

When you look at the browser console, that code *should* give errors like:

> : Component returned failure code: 0x805e0006 [nsIWebNavigation.loadURI] browser.js:10592:0
>   TypeError: aDefault is undefined

Strictly speaking, this is a bug in the Greasemonkey code.

However, that is also not how `@resource` is typically used.  Normally, you would just load a specific, **and static**, file. `@resource` is meant for CSS, image, XML, etc. files... NOT a constantly changing application route.

---

If you really want a snapshot of such a site as a resource, save the page (https://stackoverflow.com/ in your example) to the same folder as your `*.user.js` file, with an `.htm` extension (very important) and `@resource` that.

So, this script works just fine:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Test
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// @resource    testresource Stack_Overflow.htm
// ==/UserScript==

var text = GM_getResourceText ('testresource');
console.log (text);
```

***after*** you have saved https://stackoverflow.com/ as `Stack_Overflow.htm` in the script's install directory.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, I get the same error message. It also is not a problem only with GM_getResourceText, I have the same issue if I try e.g. GM_getValue.
 
Could it be, that I have changed some browser configuration, so that the proper execution of the @grant is blocked somehow?

Comment: Your FF and/or GM are corrupt. Usually this is just the instance in memory. Uninstall the script.  Fully shutdown Firefox (verify with the task manager or equivalent). Restart and install my modified script.  (The question script may actually cause Firefox to go unstable because it crashes attempting to load a malformed resource.) ... ... If all that doesn't work, create a clean FF profile and try there.

Comment: It worked after a Firefox restart. What still confuses me is, that the script does not work when I use the javascript window that opens up in Firefox to edit the script (run via right click -> "Reload and Run"). There I still get the same error message. But in the web console everything looks fine. Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.